# Why is file_get_contents() faster than using fsock_open()?

Tags: php, http-headers

In PHP, sometimes I want to send an HTTP request to a remote site just to look at the response headers, so I declare it all manually and use the `fsock_open()` function.  However, this goes much slower than calling `file_get_contents()` with a remote URL (which loads the whole page content).  Why is this?  Is there a good alternative way to get just the response headers (to check if a page returns a 404 error, for example) that works as fast as `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: Should be indifferent. You're probably doing something differently, but we can't tell without code. You should also send a HEAD request if you're only interested in the headers.

Comment: I will try to post some code when I get back to it later...

Answer (score 0):

Have you just tried using curl?  You can get back the headers and also the content, if desired.

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

$useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.5) Gecko/
2008120122 Firefox/3.0.5";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

This will chase redirects, which isn't always desired.

Look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php to see what you get back in `$info`.

You can try just doing a HEAD request instead of a GET (the `CURLOPT_NOBODY` option), but I have run into problems with some servers that deny HEADs for some reason.